# Postfix Email redirection

Tags: email, postfix, redirection

Let's say i have a postfix setup on my domain , abc.com

i want to redirect all emails coming from *@dfc.com to user1@abc.com.

If original email contains user2@abc.com as TO , after redirection , i dont want to see that email in user2's inbox but user1's inbox.

Is it possible to do this in postfix ?

i've been reading these sources

http://blog.thecodingmachine.com/content/triggering-php-script-when-your-postfix-server-receives-mail

http://www.postfix.org/RESTRICTION_CLASS_README.html
http://www.postfix.org/SMTPD_PROXY_README.html

Comment: You seem to have two different questions here. You really should treat them separately.

Comment: i dont think they have seperate meaning.Can you explain why i should treat them separately ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the solution , you need to have an extra proxy for modifying email content

here is an sample of a proxy server code.

http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577260-multi-threaded-smtp-proxy/